# grails remoteLink no working as expected

Tags: ajax, jquery, grails, grails-controller

I am trying to use Ajax asynchronous call backs with grails.  In my gsp file head I have:

```
    <g:javascript library="prototype" />
```

in the body I have:

```
        <g:remoteLink controller="dashboard" action="showTime" update="time">Show the Time</g:remoteLink> 

    <div id="time"></div>
```

on my controller I have:

```
    def showTime = {
         System.print("time");
         render "The time is ";
}
```

I would expect that the div "time" in my gsp file would be replaced with the rendered text "The time is".  Instead, nothing seems to happen.  I know that my controller fires, because of the System.print but nothing is updated in the div.

I noticed that onload of the page, I get this error generated: "element.dispatch is not an event" in the prototype.js page.  If I remove

```
 <g:javascript library="prototype" />
```

I no longer get that error but the whole page is redirected to dashboard/showTime

What am I doing wrong here?

thanks
jason

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? Have you tried using the jquery javascript library?

Comment: Hello Seth, I am using 1.3.7.  If I use jquery instead of prototype, how would my above code change?  I am still kind of new to ajax.  thanks

Comment: If you have the [jQuery plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery) installed, it will add a jquery provider that will handle building the ajax callbacks. To use the plugin, you would use `<g:javascript library="jquery" />` **in place of** `<g:javascript library="prototype" />` in your gsp file.

Comment: I'll also add that the javascript error you are getting is likely the  cause of your problem but I'm afraid I don't know how to fix that for you.

Comment: great!  I'll install the plugin and give it a try.  thanks

Comment: I did as you suggest.  I installed jquery plugin.  I then replaced the library tag to jquery.  when I run my code, though, the div is not rendered.  instead, the page is redirected to dashboar/showTime.  I do get an error "Ajax is not defined.  Any ideas?

Comment: well, i added this, and it now seems to work:  <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" />  Thanks for your help

Comment: What browser and operating system are you testing this in? Can you post the whole gsp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using both jquery (or some other JS library) and prototype libraries? This problem is usually caused by using BOTH jquery.js and prototype.js. You might not be seeing jquery being loaded (maybe it's in the layout or in the < body >, check the JS libraries loaded using firebug.

If you are loading both, comment out jquery and just use prototype. Check it again and it should be working, updating the < div >. I hope that helps.